# Last Password Changed Time Stamp from Google Admin API

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to get the last password change time stamp using the below api query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin?eventName=CHANGE_PASSWORD&email=xyz@compamy.com.au
```

But it is returning for all the users without filtering the email. Could you please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure either your question was related to how obtain the user for whom the password change has been performed or for the admin that performed this change, but I updated my answer to show you also how to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

### Filtering by [USER_EMAIL](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-user-settings#REQUEST_ACCOUNT_INFO) refers to the email of the person who changed the password (which can be the admin), not necessary the user whose password was changed.

To query for the actual user, the easiest is to set `fields` to `items/events/parameters/value` and then compare the results against the desired user email.

Sample:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin?eventName=CHANGE_PASSWORD&fields=items%2Fevents%2Fparameters%2Fvalue`

**ADDITION**

Should you want to query for `USER_EMAIL` - please note that the correct query would be

`USER_EMAIL==xyz@compamy.com.au`

which in URL encoding would translate to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin?eventName=CHANGE_PASSWORD&filters=USER_EMAIL%3D%3Dxyz%40compamy.com.au`